# How to calculate generated fees from uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I try to calculate how much fees I earned for each transaction by providing liquidity.
In chunks I downloaded all swaps, mints and burns from the graph for my token pair. https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2

I read the whitepaper and as far as I understand a swap at time t should generate

```
fees earned = token0_fee + token1_fee
with
token0_fee = 0.003 * amount0In * (number of LP tokens I own at time t  / all at time t existing LP tokens)
token1_fee = 0.003 * amount1In * (number of LP tokens I own at time t  / all at time t existing LP tokens)
```

However if I sum up all fees I do not get the results displayed (Total Fees Earned) at info.uniswap.org for my account.

Additionally if I try to calculate the number of tokens in the pair contract my result also differs from the token pair page at info.uniswap.org. I used the following formula.

```
(all tokens paid in at swaps) - (all tokens paid out at swaps) + (all tokens paid in at mints) -
(all tokens paid out at burns)
```

What am I missing here ?
Thanks